# Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_TIMESTAMP" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: h2

Can someone help me out here- getting following errors while running DML commands.

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_TIMESTAMP" not found; SQL statement:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar exception (`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function  "TO_TIMESTAMP" not found`) when upgrading `h2` from `1.4.2` to `2.2.202`

I don't know why, but it appears that the function had been removed

To make it work, I replaced `to_timestamp` by [parsedatetime](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime)

`parsedatetime` follow the [java.text.SimpleDataFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) semantics

---

**Edit** : Another way would be to add compatibity mode to Oracle (`Mode=Oracle`):

Example in spring boot : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64799048/1546137

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got this answer, we were using older version of **h2** database dependency in our project. 
for Quick fixed,Take out latest dependency and add in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.195</version>
 </dependency>
```

1. http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html
2. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2