# How to change default mode of H2 without changing the jdbc url?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Is there a way to change default compatability mode of H2 Database without specifying it inside `spring.datasource.url` each time?
Something like:

```
spring.h2.mode=ORACLE (does not work)
```

Comment: Does this help?: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

Comment: Also, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64799048/3368818

Comment: @JWoodchuck Thanks. But I want to avoid changing each url, rather change the dafault mode globally